Trying to restart a game in pygame
I am trying to make a snake game and the only issue I am having is that when the game over screen comes up and you click the restart button, it will bring up the splash screen like I want it to, but will not reset the snake position so you just lose instantly. In the gameOver function I am trying to have it set so, when you click the retry button, it will bring up the starting splash screen and will put the snake back in it's starting position.
#Project Snake
#Bryce Jones
#Code by Gareth Halfacres, Raspberry Pi Guide Book
#Reference: https://scitechdaily.com/astronomers-reveal-a-breathtaking-new-composite-image-of-the-crab-nebula/
#Reference cont.: https://scitechdaily.com/astronomers-uncover-black-hole-closer-to-earth-than-ever-before/
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *

import os
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS']='{},{}'.format(600,150)

pygame.init()

pygame.mixer.init()

fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

display = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 250), pygame.SRCALPHA, 32)

yellow = pygame.Color(255,255,0)
red = pygame.Color(255,0,0)
green = pygame.Color(0,255,0)
blue = pygame.Color(0,0,255)
black = pygame.Color(0,0,0)
white = pygame.Color(255,255,255)
grey = pygame.Color(150,150,150)

score = 0
score_increment = 10

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))

snakePosition = [100,100]
snakeSegments = [[100,100],[80,100],[60,100]]
raspberry = pygame.image.load('00_berrysprites.png').convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load('01_berrysprites.png').convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load('02_berrysprites.png').convert_alpha(), pygame.image.load('03_berrysprites.png').convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load('04_berrysprites.png').convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load('05_berrysprites.png').convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load('06_berrysprites.png').convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load('07_berrysprites.png').convert_alpha()
raspberryPosition = [300,300]
raspberrySpawned = 1

direction = 'right'
changeDirection = direction

print('\n\n\t\tProject Snake Game by Bryce Jones\n')
print('\nStarting # Snake Segments = ',snakeSegments)

def splash_screen():
    """creates splash screen"""
    done = False

    pygame.display.set_caption('Slightly Solid Snake')
    splash_background_image = pygame.image.load("capture.jpg").convert()
    screen.blit(splash_background_image, [0, 0])
    
    pygame.draw.rect(display, (0,255,0,0),(270,50,100,50))
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)
    text = font.render ("Start Game", 1, (0,0,255))
    display.blit(text, (273,70))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, (255,255,255,255),(550,440,150,150))
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)
    text = font.render ("Quit Game", 1, (0,0,0))
    display.blit(text, (550,450))
    splashScreenFont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',50)
    splashScreenSurf = splashScreenFont.render('...Slightly Solid Snake...',True,green)
    splashScreenRect = splashScreenSurf.get_rect()
    splashScreenRect.midtop = (330,200)
    screen.blit(splashScreenSurf, splashScreenRect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    
    while not done:
 
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.quit:
                done = True
            
            if event.type  == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouseX = event.pos[0]
                mouseY = event.pos[1]

                print(mouseX,mouseY)

                if (mouseX >= 270) and (mouseX < 270 + 100) and (mouseY >= 50) and (mouseY < 50 + 50):
                    print('Game Start')
                    done = True

                elif (mouseX >= 550) and (mouseX < 550 + 150) and (mouseY >= 440) and (mouseY < 440+150):
                    exit()
                
                else:
                    print('Click Start')


splash_screen()

    
def gameOver():
    """creates splash screen"""
    done = False
    
    pygame.display.set_caption('You Lose')
    splash_background_image = pygame.image.load("black_hole.jpg").convert()
    screen.blit(splash_background_image, [0, 0])

    pygame.draw.rect(display, (255,0,0,0),(270,50,100,50))
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)
    text = font.render ("Retry?", 1, (0,0,255))
    display.blit(text, (290,70))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, (255,255,255,255),(550,440,150,150))
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)
    text = font.render ("Quit Game", 1, (0,0,0))
    display.blit(text, (550,450))
    splashScreenFont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',50)
    splashScreenSurf = splashScreenFont.render('...Game Over...',True,red)
    splashScreenRect = splashScreenSurf.get_rect()
    splashScreenRect.midtop = (330,200)
    screen.blit(splashScreenSurf, splashScreenRect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    print('Game Over')
    
    while not done:
 
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.quit:
                done = True
            
            if event.type  == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouseX = event.pos[0]
                mouseY = event.pos[1]

                print(mouseX,mouseY)

                if (mouseX >= 270) and (mouseX < 270 + 100) and (mouseY >= 50) and (mouseY < 50 + 50):
                    print('Game Restart')
                    done = True
                    snakePosition = [100,100]
                    snakeSegments = [[100,100],[80,100],[60,100]]
                    splash_screen()

                elif (mouseX >= 550) and (mouseX < 550 + 150) and (mouseY >= 440) and (mouseY < 440+150):
                    exit()

                else:
                    print('Click Retry')


done = False

while not done:
    pygame.display.set_caption('Slightly Solid Snake')
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                changeDirection = 'right'
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                changeDirection = 'left'
            if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                changeDirection = 'up'
            if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                changeDirection = 'down'
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(QUIT))

    if changeDirection == 'right' and not direction == 'left':
        direction = changeDirection
    if changeDirection == 'left' and not direction == 'right':
        direction = changeDirection
    if changeDirection == 'up' and not direction == 'down':
        direction = changeDirection
    if changeDirection == 'down' and not direction == 'up':
        direction = changeDirection
    if direction == 'right':
        snakePosition[0] +=20
    if direction == 'left':
        snakePosition[0] -=20
    if direction == 'up':
        snakePosition[1] -=20
    if direction == 'down':
        snakePosition[1] +=20

    snakeSegments.insert(0,list(snakePosition))

    if snakePosition[0] == raspberryPosition[0] and snakePosition[1] == raspberryPosition[1]:
        raspberrySpawned = 0
        pygame.mixer.music.load('gworp.mp3')
        pygame.mixer.music.play(0)
        score += score_increment
        print (score)

        print('Updated # Segments: ',snakeSegments)
        pygame.display.flip()
        
    else:
        snakeSegments.pop()

    if raspberrySpawned == 0:
        x = random.randrange(1,32)
        y = random.randrange(1,24)
        raspberryPosition = [x*20,y*20]
        raspberrySpawned = 1

    game_background_image = pygame.image.load('crab_nebula.jpg').convert()
    screen.blit(game_background_image, [0,0])
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)
    text = font.render(f'Score: {score}', True, (255,255,255))
    display.blit(text, (273,50))

    pygame.display.flip()

    for position in snakeSegments:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,yellow,Rect(position[0],position[1],20,20))
       #snake = pygame.image.load('snake.png').convert_alpha()
       #screen.blit(snake, (snakePosition[0], snakePosition[1],20,20))
       #pygame.display.flip

    for rasp in raspberry:
        screen.blit(rasp,(raspberryPosition[0], raspberryPosition[1],20,20))
        pygame.display.flip()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    
    if snakePosition[0] > 620 or snakePosition[0] < 0:
        pygame.mixer.music.load('dazed_sound.mp3')
        pygame.mixer.music.play(0)
        gameOver()
    if snakePosition[1] > 460 or snakePosition[1] < 0:
        pygame.mixer.music.load('dazed_sound.mp3')
        pygame.mixer.music.play(0)
        gameOver()

    for snakeBody in snakeSegments[1:]:
         if snakePosition[0] == snakeBody[0] and snakePosition[1] == snakeBody[1]:
             pygame.mixer.music.load('dazed_sound.mp3')
             pygame.mixer.music.play(0)
             gameOver()
    fpsClock.tick(3)
pygame.quit()



you assign new value to local variable. In function you have to use global snakePosition to inform function that you want to assign value to global/external variable. OR keep all values in external list or dictionary.

You assign new value to local variable. In function you have to use global snakePosition to inform function that you want to assign value to global/external variable. OR keep all values in external list or dictionary.
def gameOver():
    global snakePosition
    global snakeSegments

    # ... rest ...


Or maybe set these values in main loop - after running gameOver() - like this:
    if snakePosition[0] > 620 or snakePosition[0] < 0:
        pygame.mixer.music.load('dazed_sound.mp3')
        pygame.mixer.music.play(0)

        gameOver()

        snakePosition = [100,100]
        snakeSegments = [[100,100],[80,100],[60,100]]

And you have to do it after every gameOver()
